# LINQ Filter rows based on LEFT JOIN

Tags: c#, linq

I want a LINQ query to have two behaviours, dependant on a parameter.

If param = -1, return all rows

If param > -1, return select rows

This is what I have tried. It emulates how I'd write it in SQL server (a left join with a where clause to force it to an inner join if param > -1), but it does not behave the same. It always returns filtered rows, behaving as if the RTA join is an inner join.

```
                // Get attributes filtered to the template (-1 = all)
            var result2 = from RA in ent.ReportAttributes 
                          join FT in ent.FilterTypes on RA.FilterTypeID equals FT.FilterTypeID
                          join DS in ent.DataSources on RA.DataSourceID equals DS.DataSourceID
                          join RTA in ent.ReportTemplateAttributes.DefaultIfEmpty() on RA.AttributeID equals RTA.AttributeID
                          where templateID == -1 || (templateID != -1 && RTA.TemplateID == templateID)
                          select new HRFWeb.Models.ReportAttributeModel()
                         {
                             AttributeGroupID = RA.AttributeGroupID,
                             AttributeID = RA.AttributeID,
                             ParentID = RA.ParentID,
                             Name = RA.Name,
                             Alias = RA.Alias,
                             IsCalculated = RA.IsCalculated,
                             FilterTypeID = RA.FilterTypeID,
                             FilterType = FT.Name,
                             DataSourceID = RA.DataSourceID,
                             DBName = DS.DBName,
                             ServerName = DS.ServerName,
                             ServerIP = DS.ServerIP,
                             DataSourceTable = RA.DataSourceTable,
                             LogiDataType = RA.LogiDataType
                         };
```

And to further demonstrate, here is the working SQL equivalent:

```
DECLARE @TemplateID INT = -1
-- Returns 53 rows (correct)
SELECT * FROM dbo.ReportAttribute RA
JOIN dbo.FilterType FT ON FT.FilterTypeID = RA.FilterTypeID
JOIN dbo.DataSource DS ON DS.DataSourceID = RA.DataSourceID
LEFT JOIN dbo.ReportTemplateAttribute RTA ON RTA.AttributeID = RA.AttributeID
WHERE @TemplateID = -1 OR (@TemplateID > -1 AND RTA.TemplateID = @TemplateID)


SET @TemplateID = 0
-- Returns 32 rows (correct)
SELECT * FROM dbo.ReportAttribute RA
JOIN dbo.FilterType FT ON FT.FilterTypeID = RA.FilterTypeID
JOIN dbo.DataSource DS ON DS.DataSourceID = RA.DataSourceID
LEFT JOIN dbo.ReportTemplateAttribute RTA ON RTA.AttributeID = RA.AttributeID
WHERE @TemplateID = -1 OR (@TemplateID > -1 AND RTA.TemplateID = @TemplateID)
```

Comment: Are we talking about Linq to Entities?

Comment: It's using the entity framework (ent), not sure if it's LINQ to SQL or LINQ to entities

Comment: Whats the relation between RA and RTA 1..1?

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger  1 to 1. Basically report template attribute is a linker table, allowing me to filter specific attributes per template.

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger It's 1 to many, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. The idea is to filter ReportTemplateAttributes after joining. And to make a left join, combination of `into group` and `select xxx from group.DefaultIfEmpty()` is required.

```
var result2 = from RA in ent.ReportAttributes 
                          join FT in ent.FilterTypes on RA.FilterTypeID equals FT.FilterTypeID
                          join DS in ent.DataSources on RA.DataSourceID equals DS.DataSourceID
                          join RTA in ent.ReportTemplateAttributes on RA.AttributeID equals RTA.AttributeID into g1
                          from g in g1 
                          select new HRFWeb.Models.ReportAttributeModel()
                          {
                             AttributeGroupID = RA.AttributeGroupID,
                             AttributeID = RA.AttributeID,
                             ParentID = RA.ParentID,
                             Name = RA.Name,
                             Alias = RA.Alias,
                             IsCalculated = RA.IsCalculated,
                             FilterTypeID = RA.FilterTypeID,
                             FilterType = FT.Name,
                             DataSourceID = RA.DataSourceID,
                             DBName = DS.DBName,
                             ServerName = DS.ServerName,
                             ServerIP = DS.ServerIP,
                             DataSourceTable = RA.DataSourceTable,
                             LogiDataType = RA.LogiDataType,
                             TemplateID = g.TemplateID
                           };

   if (FilterTemplateId != -1) {
     result2 = from r in result2
               where r.TemplateID == FilterTemplateID
               select r;
     }
```

Comment: Has the opposite effect, returns all 53 rows no matter what templateID is.

Comment: Of course, left join is not needed in this case. I've update the answer

Comment: Now it always returns the filtered rows... I'm thinking of just writing a sproc :)

Comment: Strange. I guess this is what happens when I cannot debug my own code. I've updated the answer: added left join and moved filter to if statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result2 = from RA in ent.ReportAttributes 
                      join FT in ent.FilterTypes on RA.FilterTypeID equals FT.FilterTypeID
                      join DS in ent.DataSources on RA.DataSourceID equals DS.DataSourceID               
                      where templateID == -1 || (RA.TemplateAttributes != null && RA.TemplateAttributes.Any(rt=> rt.TemplateID == templateID))
                      select new HRFWeb.Models.ReportAttributeModel()
                     {
                         AttributeGroupID = RA.AttributeGroupID,
                         AttributeID = RA.AttributeID,
                         ParentID = RA.ParentID,
                         Name = RA.Name,
                         Alias = RA.Alias,
                         IsCalculated = RA.IsCalculated,
                         FilterTypeID = RA.FilterTypeID,
                         FilterType = FT.Name,
                         DataSourceID = RA.DataSourceID,
                         DBName = DS.DBName,
                         ServerName = DS.ServerName,
                         ServerIP = DS.ServerIP,
                         DataSourceTable = RA.DataSourceTable,
                         LogiDataType = RA.LogiDataType
                     };
```

By use of the navigation Property... The second check templateID != -1 seems redundant

Comment: RTA is undefined. And you're probably right, it's redundant. Was just using belt n bracers

Comment: Look at the model if theres a navigation property ... could be a different name

Comment: Its RA.NavigationPropertyName != null && RA.NavigationPropertyName.TemplateID == templateID

Comment: The only navigation prop I can see is called ReportTemplateAttributes, and it's a collection (so can't do ReportTemplateAttributes.TemplateID). I misled you earlier, it's one to many. Sorry.

Comment: It doesn't contain any additional data, it's a filter table. So I can either load all attributes, or only load attributes that are linked to a template. So e.g. I have 100 attribs, Template1 has 50, Template2 has 25. So on.

Comment: This is not easy because i dont have your model... i hope i can get there so bear with me

Comment: Now it's giving an enumeration error. I've had to move on and do it as a sproc entity call instead, due to time pressures. I appreciate your help.